# AngularJS: Infinite $digest loop error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing [this](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial) tutorial and can't get my page to load correctly.  I keep getting `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]` in the console.

I'm very new to Angular, but from what i've read I have an infinite loop somewhere.  I anticipate it's from `o.getAll`, but I can't see how it's looping infinitely.

The entire error in the console is:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:6:417
    at l.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:124:366)
    at l.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:126:471)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:17:448
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:37:96)
    at d (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:17:369)
    at sc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:18:153)
    at Jd (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:16:483)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js:249:429(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11598(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8548l.$apply @ angular.js:14495(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1449e @ angular.js:4182d @ angular.js:1447sc @ angular.js:1467Jd @ angular.js:1361(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26086a @ angular.js:2741c @ angular.js:3011
angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

My code is below:

angularApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

          $stateProvider
              .state('home', {
                  url: '/home',
                  templateUrl: '/home.html',
                  controller: 'MainCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                      postPromise: ['posts', function (posts) {
                              return posts.getAll();
                    }]
                  }
              })
              .state('posts', {
                  url: '/posts/:id',
                  templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                  controller: 'PostsCtrl',
                  resolve: {
                  post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function ($stateParams, posts) {
                      return posts.get($stateParams.id);
              }]
          }
      });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
  }])


app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',
    function($scope, posts){
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return;}
            posts.create({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
            });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementUpVotes = function(post){
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };
    }
])


app.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];


        $scope.addComment = function(){
          if($scope.body === '') { return; }
          $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
          });
          $scope.body = '';
        };


    }

]);

app.factory('posts', ['$http', function(){

    var o = {
        posts: []
    };

      o.getAll = function () {
          return $http.get('/posts')
            .success(function (data) {
              angular.copy(data, o.posts);
          });
      };

      o.create = function (post) {
          return $http.post('/posts', post)
            .success(function (data) {
              o.posts.push(data);
          });
      };

    return o;
}]);
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- inline Template for Home -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>

    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
          ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
        {{post.upvotes}}
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
            {{post.title}}
          </a>
          <span ng-hide="post.link">
            {{post.title}}
          </span>
          <span>
            <a href = "#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Link"
          ng-model="link"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>



</script>
<!-- Inline template for posts -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>

    <form ng-submit="addComment()"
    style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Comment"
      ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

routes - index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    res.json(posts)
  });
});

router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);

    post.save(function(err, post){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(post);
    });
});

router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id){
    var query = Post.findById(id);

    query.exec(function(err, post){
        if(err) {return next(err); }
        if(!post) {return next(new Error('cant find post')); }

        req.post = post;
        return next();
    });
});
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next){
    req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post){
        if(err){ return next(err);}
    })
        res.json(req.post)
});

router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', function(req, res, next){
    req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
        if(err){return next(err);}

        res.json(post);
    });
});

router.post('/posts/:post/comments', function(req, res, next) {
    var comment = new Comment(req.body);
    comment.post = req.post;

    comment.post = req.post;

    comment.save(function(err, comment){
        if(err) { return next(err); }

        req.post.comments.push(comment);
        req.post.save(function(err, post) {
            if(err){ return next(err);}

            res.json(comment);
        });
    });
});

router.param('comment', function(req, res, next, id){
    var query = Comment.findById(id);

    query.exec(function(err, comment){
        if(err) {return next(err); }
        if(!comment) {return next(new Error('cant find comments')); }

        req.comment = comment;
        return next();
    });
});

router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', function(req, res, next){
    req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
        if(err){return next(err);}

        res.json(post);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you post the error as well please ?

Comment: Could you post *what you're doing* before you cause the error?

Comment: I'm just trying to access the homepage @DanPantry

Comment: I can suggest you one thing as far as getting a meaningful error is concerned, do not use the "min" version of Angular.... Use    

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary thanks for the tip.  I just changed it, but it's showing the same error wording and links :/

Comment: @ElliottMcNary please have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks Mate, I will do that from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to have `$http` as an argument in the `o.getAll` function.

`o.getAll = function($http)` stopped the loop.

Answer (score 1):

you just forgot to add $http param to function

```
app.factory('posts',['$http',function($http){
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix your issue, but your code can be simplified a bit like this.

You do not need to have a success handler in o.getAll(). Just return the promise that is returned by $http.get().

```
o.getAll = function () {
      return $http.get('/posts');
  };
```

Now,in your MainCtrl, you can access posts data like this:

```
function ($scope, postPromise) {
    $scope.posts = postPromise.data;
}
```